# using Kinect, error C2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, kinect

i just started using visual studio and i tryed to run the kinect samples via visual studios. So far, all samples like ColorBasic, DepthBasic-D2D, Depth-D3D worked fine, but when i try to run FaceTrackingVisualization I get an error:

```
1>d:\programme\dropbox\dropbox\uni\uni\pa_eyetracking\visualstudio\programms\samples\facetrackingvisualization\singleface\kinectsensor.cpp(435): **Error C2668: "abs": ambiguous call to overloaded function**

1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdlib.h(363): note: kann "__int64 abs(const __int64) throw()" sein

1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdlib.h(358): note: oder "long abs(const long) throw()"

1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdlib.h(288): note: oder "int abs(int)"
```

Somebody knows how to fix that error? I just used the sample code, I dont understand why is there a problem.
I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the SDK v1.8.0.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. We don't know what such "sample code" is.

Comment: Please [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47943610/edit) the argument you supply to the function.

Comment: The reason the error is happening is because there was an "ambiguous call to [an] overloaded function".  If you show us the part of the sample code that has the "abs" call then we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: Just writing here for some sensitive people to be unable to vote, replace `abs` to `fabsf` to solve the ambiguity

Comment: Replace `abs` with `std::abs`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the compiler has to type-convert from a type that it does not have an explicit parameter match and there is more that one function for which there are implicit type casts.  In this case, there are functions for int and long and long long but the type being passed in is probably either an unsigned or a float or a double.

You can change the line from std::abs(myValue) to std::abs(static_cast(myValue)), or cast to int or long based on the input type.